# c# for loops: assignment for my programming class

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop

i have the following question for one of my assignments for my programming class and was wondering if somebody could help and explain the answer for me.  We just started with loops and the book for the class isn't too helpful... the question is:

Study the following block of code carefully. When you submit your lab, add a comment to your submission that answers the following questions about this code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if ( block [i] > block [i+1])
            swap (ref block [i], ref block [i + 1]);
    }
}
```

(1) When the code above is executed, how many times is this statement executed?

```
  if ( block [i] > block [i+1])
```

Comment: 1. set a breakpoint on that line 2. run the code 3. count the number of times it stops 4. Profit (from learning how to run the debugger)

Comment: And the structure of the block array is...

Comment: Do you know what a `for` loop is? How it works? What are you missing here?

Comment: 3^2 = 9 times it executes

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting will work in this case, and it will answer the question, but i think knowing why is better.

Look at the "for" loops. All code in each block will be repeated x number of times.

In this case the first one will repeat three times, once when j = 0, once when j = 1 and once when j = 2. When j = 3, the condition of j > 3 is no longer true.

So we know that all the code in the j for loop will run three times.

So look at the next for loop... it too will loop three times.

If the outer for loop will call the "nested" for loop three times, and the nested for loop will run it's block of code three times, we know the code in the middle will run 3 times, 3 times, so 3 * 3 = 9.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code and see if it helps:

```
var count = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

I get:

```
9
```

If the code changes to this:

```
var count = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Then I get:

```
20
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply place break point on the:
     if (block[i] > block[i + 1])

Then run with "Start Debugging" and count...

But first build your array under Main:

```
        int[] block = new int[5];

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                if (block[i] > block[i + 1])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                    //swap(ref block[i], ref block[i + 1]);}
                }
            }
        }
```